# Entity framework multiple one-to-one relations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a problem with setting foreign keys to an entity which references one of three possible entities. Classes are the following:

```
public class Target
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? AttachmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Attachment Attachment { get; set; }
}
public class SubTarget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? AttachmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Attachment Attachment { get; set; }
}
public class Procedure
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? AttachmentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Attachment Attachment { get; set; }
}
public class Attachment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? TargetId { get; set; }
    public int? SubTargetId { get; set; }
    public int? ProcedureId { get; set; }
    public virtual Target Target { get; set; }
    public virtual SubTarget SubTarget { get; set; }
    public virtual Procedure Procedure { get; set; }
}
```

So, each of the three first classes may or may not have an `Attachment`, and each `Attachment` can and must reference one of the three first classes.
**Firstly:** Is it at all possible to have a foreign key setup like this?
**Secondly:** How do i accomplish it with code-first migrations?
With the current setup I get an error stating "Unable to determine the principal end of foreign-key-relations", and by commenting out the virtual properties in the `Attachment` class, the relation seems to go backwards, ie. `Target` has a foreign key that references `Attachment`.

Comment: check these links: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj591620.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have one-to-one relation in EF, add to Target, SubTarget and Procedure classes this annotation to:

```
[Key, ForeignKey("Attachments")]
public int Id {get;set;}
```

This will make Primary key same as Foreign Key.
Then remove from these 3 classes:

```
 public int? AttachmendId {get;set;}
```

Hopefully you can get this work. I've been usually struggling with one-to-one relations often, so I basically would design my tables as one-to-zero or one-to-many.
 If you need more information regarding one-to-one relations: look here
[Entity framework multiple one-to-one relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29839933/entity-framework-multiple-one-to-one-relations/29841035#29841035)

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't do the trick like one might expect. I have several other FK-relations in the tables and changing the schema at this point isn't so straightforward after all. However, I also suspect that this solution would lead to a situation where an `Attachment` must have refenreces to all 3 other classes.

Comment: I rebuilt the DB with these attributes, and as I thought, it now requires all 3 references on the `Attachment` class. So, no help from this..

Comment: What about if you just delete all the references back to attachment? Just have Attachment foreign key to those other classes?